# Initial state of element to be animated in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I have an element that i would like off screen to begin with, but then on click of a link, that element gets animated in (using animate.css). But, i'm not sure what css method to use to hide that element off screen so it can be animated in.

The js i'm using is:

```
$('.services-wrapper').on('click','.services-panel__cta',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.services-panel__secondary').addClass('animated bounceInright');
})
```

And i have tried doing:

```
position: absolute;
left: 100%
```

and

```
left: -9999px
```

But i'm not sure that even makes sense to try tbh.

Any help really gratefully received!

Comment: To hide it just off the screen, personally I would do left: -(width of element)

Comment: @aw04 That doesn't work i'm afraid.

Comment: What do you mean, it's just a value. What happens?

Comment: Well, as you can see in the question, i have already tried negative values to move it off screen which hides the element, but then it doesn't animate it in. it just stays off screen.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it... I'm not sure you need to do anything with animate.css. Doesn't it take care of that for you?

Comment: I think you are thinking about animate.css with wow.js. This is just animate.css.

Comment: See my answer for details..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With animate.css, you don't need to specify the position beforehand. You can hide it with `display: none;` and then add an additional class that adds `display: block;`.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/087v2zqx/4/)

CSS

```
.services-panel__secondary {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$('.services-wrapper').on('click', '.services-panel__cta', function() {
  $('.services-panel__secondary').addClass('show animated bounceInRight');
})
```

---

**Or just use `show()` instead of adding the class:**

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/087v2zqx/3/)

```
$('.services-wrapper').on('click', '.services-panel__cta', function() {
  $('.services-panel__secondary').show().addClass('animated bounceInRight');
});
```

---

**And Lastly**

If you can edit the html directly, you can add the animate.css classes directly and just `show()` the element:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/087v2zqx/5/)

Add classes in html and hide with `display: block;`

```
<div class="services-panel__secondary animated bounceInRight">
  Bounce this in
</div>
```

JQuery- Simply show it and it will bounce in.

```
$('.services-wrapper').on('click', '.services-panel__cta', function() {
  $('.services-panel__secondary').show();
})
```

---

***IMPORTANT:***

With animate.css, notice that "right" should have an uppercase "R" like `bounceInRight`

Answer (score 0):

animate.css actually takes care of this for you with it's animations. Check out the source of bounceInRight (which you are using). As you can see, it moves the x-value around using `transform: trasnslate3d(...)`. As mentioned by 
@dwreck08 (+1), you only need to worry about hide/show.

```
@keyframes bounceInRight {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A solution which allows animating in and out**

This example code comes from [Animate.css](https://animate.style/)'s own documentation. I have expanded on it to include adding and removing a `show` class, which will maintain state once the animation is complete.

```
const animateCSS = (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') => {
    // Create a Promise and return it
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
        const node = document.querySelector(element);

        // Add class to display element when animating in
        if (animation.indexOf('In') >= 0)
            node.classList.add('show');

        node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

        // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
        function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();

            // Remove class to display element when animating out
            if (animation.indexOf('Out') >= 0)
                node.classList.remove('show');

            node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);
            resolve('Animation ended');
        }

        node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd, { once: true });
    });
}
```

Set initial styles to `display: none` and create a `show` class with `display: block`. Then call the method we created with the following:

```
animateCSS('.services-panel__secondary', 'bounceInright');
```